Laravel 11 get data from DB is null even though data exist
So in my laravel 11 project i'm making a function to export data to excel based on the search and the selected category, so the problem is it wont get any data even though the data exist in db. And the weird things are if the data is less than 3 results null, if 4 results only 1, if 5 result 2, 7 result only 5. And if the data is more than 10 then its no problem. in the controller i've checked that the input for search and category are passed to the controller. can anyone help me with it? also i use softDelete if that relevant
Controller
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Products;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;
use App\Exports\ProductsExport;

    class ExportController extends Controller
    {
        /**
         * Export products to Excel.
         *
         * @param  Request  $request
         * @return \Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel
         */
        public function export(Request $request)
        {
            $search = strval($request->input('search'));
            $category = $request->input('category');
    
            // dd($search, $category); successfully get data
    
            $query = Products::query();
    
            if ($search !== '') {
                $query->whereRaw('nama LIKE ?', ["%{$search}%"]);
            }
    
            if (!is_null($category)) {
                $query->where('kategori_id', $category);
            }
    
            // dd($query->toSql()); result: "select * from "products" where nama LIKE ? and "kategori_id" = ? and "products"."deleted_at" is null" 
    
            $products = $query->get();
    
            // dd($products);
    
            if ($products->isEmpty()) {
                return redirect()->back()->withErrors('No Data to Export');
            }
    
            $timestamp = date('Y-m-d_H-i-s');
            $filename = 'products_' . $timestamp . '.xlsx';
    
            return Excel::download(new ProductsExport($products), $filename);
        }
    }

the input form in the blade
<form action="{{ route('export.products') }}" method="post" class="flex flex-wrap justify-between items-center mb-4 gap-2">
            @csrf
            <div class="flex flex-wrap gap-2">
                <div class="relative w-full md:w-auto">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Cari barang" id="search" name="search" class="border p-2 pl-10 rounded w-full">
                    <span class="absolute inset-y-0 left-0 flex items-center pl-3">
                        <i class="fas fa-search text-gray-400"></i>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <select name="category" id="category" class="border p-2 rounded w-full md:w-auto">
                    <option value="">Semua</option>
                    @foreach($kategoris as $kategori)
                        <option value="{{ $kategori->id }}">{{ $kategori->name }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="flex space-x-2 ml-auto">
                <button type="submit" class="bg-green-700 text-white text-sm px-3 py-2 rounded hover:bg-green-600">
                    <i class="fa-regular fa-file-excel lg:mr-2"></i>
                    <span class="hidden md:inline">Export Excel</span>
                </button>
                <a href="/products/add" class="bg-red-600 text-white text-sm px-3 py-2 rounded hover:bg-red-500">
                    <i class="fas fa-plus lg:mr-2"></i>
                    <span class="hidden md:inline">Tambah Produk</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </form>

I want to get all the data not partially or null, then i proceed to export into excel

Still need help with this matter?
